# Need to run a PHP script when a audio player starts

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on a website for a radio station.
Took me a while to find a nice script that would pull the Metadata from the stream so I can put this on the site beneath the player.
So I got the PHP code from some people far smarter then I am ;)

The PHP script spits out some like this : string(15) "Toto - Only You"

Now I am facing two problems.

1. I need the Php script to run in a timed execution every 60 seconds while the player ( Script player ) is running ( Play button clicked ).
2. The value that the PHP script spits out needs to be trimmed down to not show the string(15) part of the text.

For you wizards this is probably a piece of cake but I am at a loss here finding a way to implement this.  Any suggestions anyone could give me would be much appreciated.

For your info :
This is the Script code that makes up the player :

```
<!--  RADIO PLAYER CODE -->
<script src="https://hosted.muses.org/mrp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
    },
    BlackBerry: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
    },
    Opera: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
    },
    Windows: function() {
        return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
 if( isMobile.any() ) {
MRP.insert({
'url':'http://live.radiorijen.nl/lq',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':100,
'autoplay':false,
'buffering':5,
'title':'Radio Rijen LQ',
'welcome':'Welkom bij...',
'wmode':'transparent',
'skin':'alberto',
'width':250,
'height':95
});} 
else
MRP.insert({
'url':'http://live.radiorijen.nl/hq',
'codec':'mp3',
'volume':100,
'autoplay':false,
'buffering':5,
'title':'Radio Rijen HQ',
'welcome':'Welkom bij...',
'wmode':'transparent',
'skin':'alberto',
'width':250,
'height':95
});

</script>
<!-- ENDS RADIO PLAYER CODE -->
```

The Php Script:

```
<?php

    /**
     * Please be aware. This gist requires at least PHP 5.4 to run correctly.
     * Otherwise consider downgrading the $opts array code to the classic "array" syntax.
     */
    function getMp3StreamTitle($streamingUrl, $interval, $offset = 0, $headers = true)
    {
        $needle = 'StreamTitle=';
        $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36';

        $opts = [
            'http' => [
                'method' => 'GET',
                'header' => 'Icy-MetaData: 1',
                'user_agent' => $ua
            ]
        ];

        if (($headers = get_headers($streamingUrl)))
            foreach ($headers as $h)
                if (strpos(strtolower($h), 'icy-metaint') !== false && ($interval = explode(':', $h)[1]))
                    break;

        $context = stream_context_create($opts);

        if ($stream = fopen($streamingUrl, 'r', false, $context))
        {
            while($buffer = stream_get_contents($stream, $interval, $offset)) {
                if (strpos($buffer, $needle) !== false)
                {
                    fclose($stream);
                    $title = explode($needle, $buffer)[1];
                    return substr($title, 1, strpos($title, ';') -2 );
                }

                $offset += $interval;
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump(getMp3StreamTitle('http://live.radiorijen.nl/hq', 19200));

    echo "\n\n";

?>
```

Comment: have you started coding? StackOverflow is a site for programming questions. We can't help you if you can't show us any code.

Comment: Thanks Kevin for pointing this out. I have edited the entry above with the code I am using. May not be the best code out there, but it seems to do what it has to, now for getting them to play nice....

Comment: I have solved the issue with the PHP script outputting the raw string. Just replaced VAR_DUMP with ECHO. ;)

1 Down , 1 to go.

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer. this will help others that might have the same problem. win-win. you solve your problem, you also help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. I would leverage JS/JQuery to execute a call to the PHP Every 60 seconds. This can be linked by the player or a `setInterval`.
2. Edit the `var_dump(getMp3StreamTitle('http://live.radiorijen.nl/hq', 19200));` from your PHP and determine how you want to format the output. You can use `echo` or `printf`. The `var_dump()` is what is giving you the extra detail.

Comment: I had been looking at an option to perhaps use sleep(60) and to have the PHP script rerun itself, but your suggestion to do it with ajax might be better. I'll look around to find some code that will allow me to start and run a timer or stop the php execution.